# How to get and pass the data from a form in Laravel, and check its validation with data in SQL database?

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, validation

I'm new to Laravel. I have a login form for administrators written in Laravel, a model Admin, AdminLoginController and HTML. I want to get the data from it, and check with admin data in SQL database. For example, a person signs in the form with his/her email and password. After clicking submit button, the data will be compared to the data in the MySQL database (PHPMyadmin). If signing in successfully, it will be redirected to the view 'home'.

```
            <form
                action="{{
                    url('home/admin/',[$info->id])
                }}"
                method="post"
                role="form"
                style="
                    width: 900px;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    align-items: flex-end;
                "
            >
                @method('post')
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div
                    class="input-label"
                    style="
                        flex: 1;
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                    "
                >
                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                </div>
                <div
                    class="input-box"
                    style="
                        flex: 6;
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: column;
                    "
                >
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" step="any" min="0" max="100" value="{{$info->email}}"/>
                    <input type="text" id="password" name="password" step="any" min="0" max="100" value="{{$info->password}}"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I initialized the data variable $info:

```
<?php
    $info = [];
?>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public static function loginCheckAdmin(Request $request): bool
    {
        $email = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;
        if (Admin::query()->find($email) === null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $fetchedPassword = Admin::query()->where('email',$email)->get('password');
            if ($fetchedPassword === $password)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public static function redirectAdminToHome(Request $request)
    {
        if (self::loginCheckAdmin($request) === true)
        {
            $email = $request->email;
            $id = Admin::query()->where('email',$email)->get('id');
            redirect()->to('home/admin'.$id);
            self::updateAdminLoginTime($request);
        }
        else
        {
            self::denyUserAccess($request);
        }
    }
    public static function denyUserAccess(Request $request)
    {
        echo("Invalid login process!");
    }
    public static function updateAdminLoginTime(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->email;
        $lastLoginTime = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        Admin::query()->where('email',$email)->update(['last_login_time',$lastLoginTime]);
    }
```

So I want to ask how to initialize $info because the server always says "Attempt to read property "id" on array", and how to validate the data with the database. Thanks for any help!

Comment: with an array use [ ] to get a value

Comment: @ericmp I already defined <?php $info = []; ?>. How to assign the attribute of $info to be email and password?

Comment: not sure what r u trying to do here, but u can push a key + value into the array this way: `$info['email'] = 'my email';`

Comment: @ericmp In short, I'm trying to get admin email and password from a form and then check if they are in the admin database. If yes then redirect to view 'home' and update the last_login_time in the database. Thanks for helping!

Comment: in what line the error is happening?

Comment: @ericmp the error is located at action="{{
                    url('home/admin/',[$info->id])
                }}"

Comment: did u try to `{{ url('home/admin/',[$info['id']]) }}` instead? but anyways, if `$info` is `[]`, u wouldn't be able to retrieve the id

Comment: @ericmp I did try and nothing happened. The error is still the same "Undefined array key "id"".

Comment: the error is not the same. before: `Attempt to read property "id" on array` now: `Undefined array key "id"`. the error is telling u what is happening

Comment: @ericmp Can I have a little chat with you? I don't understand about the array key "id" since I don't know if it exists.

Comment: yeah sure, `Undefined array key "id"` just means that in the array there is no key called `id`. u know what an associative array is?

Answer (score 0):

just use the breeze pakage for laravel basic login

open cmd in root of the project

- php artisan breeze:install
- php artisan migrate
- npm install
- npm run dev

it handles basic user registration and authentication.